# making an angular app from html to render data from http rest endpoint using $http

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest

I am an absolute beginner with angularjs. My problem statement is to fetch the data from the database and show it as a grid. I am trying to render the data from the rest end point on clicking the anchor tag "Data Profiling". what is the best way to do it.

This is my first post in stackoverflow so please excuse any mistakes in the post.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="d2vapp">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>D2V</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <a name="about"></a>
    <div class="intro-header" ng-controller="d2vappcontroller">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="intro-message">
                        <h1>Data to Value</h1>
                        <h3>Your one stop data explorer</h3>
                        <hr class="intro-divider">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                        <table align='center' width=100%>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><span class="network-name">Data Catalogue</span></a></br></br>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><span class="network-name">Data Exploration</span></a></br></br>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#" id="rundeck" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><span class="dataprofiling">Data Profiling</span></a></br></br>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-md"><span class="network-name">API Catalogue</span></a></br></br>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <a href="http://cstg-sa-adm-dev-01:4440/"  class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><span class="network-name">RUNDECK</span></a></br></br>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <a href="http://cstg-sa-ssot-dev-07:8000/kibana/#/dashboard/PDI-Prod-DashBoard?_g=(time:(from:now-90d,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!(),panels:!((col:1,id:prod-pdi-job-average-processed-time,row:1,size_x:6,size_y:7,type:visualization),(col:7,id:prod-pdi-job-start-time-and-end-time,row:1,size_x:6,size_y:7,type:visualization),(col:1,id:prod-pdi-actual-log,row:8,size_x:12,size_y:13,type:search)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:'PDI%20Prod%20DashBoard')" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><span class="">Infra Management</span></a></br></br>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.intro-header -->

    <!-- Page Content -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="footer-menu-divider">&sdot;</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="footer-menu-divider">&sdot;</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#services">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="footer-menu-divider">&sdot;</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="copyright text-muted small">Copyright &copy; Cisco 2016. All Rights Reserved</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularJS javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have to inject the **$http** and **$scope**

```
angular.module('d2vapp').controller('d2vappcontroller' , function($scope, $http){
      $scope.getDataProfiling = function(){

           $http.get('path/to/your/route')
               .success(function(response){
                     //do something with your response
               })
               .error(function(error){
                     //handle your error
               });
      }
});
```

In your html add the click action

```
<a href="#" id="rundeck" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" ng-click="getDataProfiling()"><span class="dataprofiling">Data Profiling</span></a></br></br>
```

**NOTE:** Please go through the [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) for better understanding how various components of angular work

Comment: i tried the code you provided but it doesn't seem to be working on click.